# How do I do a 'LIKE' search in datajoint?

Tags: python, datajoint

To do a normal search in datajoint you do -

```py
some_table & { 'some_column': 'opq'  }
```

suppose I want to search for combinatios of 'opq', like 'aopq', 'opqb', 'abopqgt' and other suffix and/or prefix combinations, how do I do that? I do not recall seeing it in documentation